# Input sequence is read even when loop breaks (in command line)

Tags: c++

how can I deal with this problem?

```
while(ntestcase--)
{
    int i, n, max;
    cin >> n;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a;

        if(a >= 2)
            max += 2;
        else
            break;
    }

    cout << "max=" << max << " n=" << n << " i=" << i << "\n";

    if(i == n && max != 0)
        cout << max << "\n";
    else
        cout << -1;
}
```

consider the input

```
ntestcase=3
n=5
as a's
1 2 3 4 5
```

My basic inference of the problem is,
here 5 a's are to be entered, but when 1 is encountered loop breaks and output is given.
There after from the same input 2 is considered as 'n' for next test case
and a's as 3, 4 and output is given and then n as 5.

the output produced is somewhat like this:

```
max=0 n=5 i=0
-1
max=4 n=2 i=2
4
```

How can I get this solved and consider the sequence (example: `1 2 3 4 5` )as a single input?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't make out what you're saying.

Comment: Is this a Hackerrank problem? Link?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your analysis of the error is correct.
When you break out of the loop, unread input intended for the
current iteration of `while(ntestcase--)` is left over and is
used as input for the next iteration.

I would probably write all of this code very differently if I were
writing my own program  (for one thing, I would avoid using the same variable `i` to count both how many times `a` was read from the input *and* how many of these were before the first value less than 2), but to continue in the style you've already chosen:

Add another `for` loop at the end of the body of `while(ntestcase--)`
to consume the rest of that iteration's input without doing anything else.
Consume `n - i` values from the input,
and then you will be ready for the next iteration of `while(ntestcase--)`.

For example, this would probably do the job:

```
int how_many_to_discard = n - i;
for (int j = 0; j < how_many_to_discard; ++j)
{
  cin >> a;
}
```

Or if you don't want to give away too many clues to anyone who might want to debug the code, the loop could instead be

```
for ( ; i < n; ++i)
```

Comment: When you gave the value 5 to `n`, you expected the program to read 5 numbers.
As you broke the read+compute loop sooner, the program read less values. So you must read+discard the remaining numbers.